# How to compare outputs from one thread with outputs from another thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a program in C++ to Parallelize the process of converting elements of an array with the `~` operator. The elements are ones and zeros. So I wanted the program to convert ones to zeroes and *vice versa*. The code is working and now I want to compare the outputs of thread 0 to outputs of thread 1 but I do not know how to do it. My code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2); 
    char array[6]={1,0,1,0,1,0,};


    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       
          cout << "Number of available threads: " << omp_get_num_threads() << endl;

              cout << "Current thread number is: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;

                for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array); i++)

            {   
                bitset<M> bitarray(array[i]);

                cout << ~bitarray << " ";
                    
    }   cout<< endl<<endl;

     }
            }
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Number of available threads: 2
Current thread number is: 0
11111110 11111111 11111110 11111111 11111110 11111111 

Number of available threads: 2
Current thread number is: 1
11111110 11111111 11111110 11111111 11111110 11111111
```

How can I compare and confirm that these two outputs are identical?

Comment: Can you run your code through an autoformatter? After all, you want people to read it, or? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options I can suggest (which are generally very similar to each other)

1. in each thread output the answer to another file. When all threads are complete, just compare the contents of the files
2. create an array of [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) in which output the required variables, and compare the contents of these stringstreams